# Настройка launch.json vscode

Tags: c, json, visual-studio, отладка, visual-studio-code

Пытаюсь запустить дебаг в vscode и вылетает ошибка, что программы " не существует и предлагает настроить `launch.json`
Установлены `C/C++` и `C++ Intellisense` дополнения

```
{
            "name": "(Windows) Launch",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true
        }
```

Вот все, что есть в конфигурации `launch.json`. Может кто рассказать, что и где прописать, что бы дебажить простые коды на Си?

Comment: gdb установлен?

Comment: Да, 7.6.1. у меня весь basic MinGW установлен

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp